# How to differentiate between a mapped type with Pick and the original type when all properties are optional

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

I have a picked type `ColumnSetting` where the original type `Column` has almost all properties as optional:

```
type ColumnSetting = Pick<Column, 'colId' | 'width' | 'sort'>;

type Column = {
  colId: string,
  width?: number,
  sort?: number
  something?: string
}
```

`Column` has several more properties than `ColumnSetting`. However wherever `ColumnSetting` is used as a type the TS engine accepts `Column` without complaints. How can I define `ColumnSetting`
to make the TS engine not allow `Column` where `ColumnSetting` is expected?

Comment: Please provide expected bahavior? I mean if you expect TS error please leave a comment

Comment: Yes I expect a TS error when Column is used instead of ColumnSetting, but exactly what error the compiler would choose is not something I have knowledge about. But I don't expect that currently only after the ColumnSetting definition has been imrpoved and the question is how to improve it so that TS generates an error? Shouldn't it be possible to restrict the max number of properties in the ColumnSetting definition? export type ColumnSetting = Max3Props<Pick<Column, 'colId' | 'width' | 'sort'>>; But how would I write Max3Props?

Comment: Please consider giving us a [mre] including the definition of `Column` and the particular problem you're running into.  TypeScript types are open and not sealed so extra properties don't necessarily violate a type.  I could make a guess like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZjo4m) (which has an `ExclusivePick` helper type defined) but it would be so much nicer for you to provide the type for us.  Please comment and mention @jcalz after you do this and I'll come back with an answer.

Comment: @jcalz ExclusivePick was exactly what I needed. You example was pretty much on point! Thanks! If added as an answer I will upvote there too. Thanks again :)

Comment: I'll write up an answer if you would [edit] the question to define `Column` for us.  Let me know once you've done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are *open* in the sense that they extra allow properties not mentioned in the declaration.    Indeed this is what makes interfaces and object types *extendible*.  Otherwise `inferface Foo {a: string}` and `interface Bar extends Foo {b: string}` would put us in the unfortunate circumstances that `Bar extends Foo` but `Bar` is not a valid `Foo`.  But `{a: string, b: string}` is assignable to `{a: string}`.

Sometimes people get confused into thinking that TypeScript types are *closed* or *sealed* or *exact* (as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)), but the closest thing TypeScript has are [excess property checks on object literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), which is more like a linter warning and not a type safety check.

That means `Pick<T, K>` is always a supertype of `T`, so `Column` will be assignable to `Pick<Column, K>` no matter what `K` is.  All `Pick` does is say that something must have certain keys, not that it must *lack* the remainder.  If you want to exclude other properties, you must do so explicitly.  TypeScript doesn't have a direct way to say "this key must not exist".  But you *can* say that a property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) and of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Since you can *never* find a value of type `never`, the only way of satisfying `{foo?: never}` is by not having a `foo` property.  (Well, or you can make it `undefined`, assuming you don't have [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) enabled.)

So you don't want `Pick`... you want something like `ExclusivePick`:

```
type ExclusivePick<T, K extends keyof T> = 
    { [P in K]: T[P] } & { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: never }
```

That is the same as `Pick<T, K>` [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with an object type that prohibits all the keys of `T` [excluding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) those in `K`.

Let's test it out:

```
type ColumnSetting = ExclusivePick<Column, 'colId' | 'width' | 'sort'>;

/* type ColumnSetting = {
    colId: string;
    width?: number | undefined;
    sort?: number | undefined;
} & {
    something?: undefined;
}*/
```

Now if you try to assign a `Column` to that, you'll get an error:

```
function foo(col: Column) {
    const columnSetting: ColumnSetting = col; // error!
    //  Types of property 'something' are incompatible.
    //  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'   
}
```

The compiler is saying that the only value it would accept for the `something` property of a `ColumnSetting` would be `undefined`, not `string`, and so `Column` is inappropriate.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2UC8UDeAoKQqAY0QEkATALigGdgAnASzQHMAaAogdyYuAAWAfhppUAIwgNOROnAbARUMSkkMuhWnBQRBLVkvrM2eAL548oSFACiAD2LJaTAG4QACk2IBrADwAVdigAaSgIO2AINApaKG8IEDgAMyh-AD4sXCgAbXcoFhCAXRp-XMKoUygAMizc-Ix7RyQKCF94xJTAkLTCpTQINwYKiytoeGR0AGVdYH1MxqdXDy8-cdQ0IIByUgRKTagAHyhN3n4BfaPNrQVNtIBuCwB6ACooUdhEdengWbZM-FkO0oNCM+geslOgj6EikhygSGiECSLAgFHBRGuilEMKGRwRLWR-TRZmquA0ch0ejYSnxSJRxNMz0eFiSCOIszgGCScDgAAodjQ1ugAJRkwGc+gkT5TGb6QXStDfX6sTI7O5QR6PMIMBjyACE5M1hH84AgsWSUDAusgChAxy0lIE+n2AEMGNAWKQUGAXbNxAgIAA6Q1a1Km+2MZ35WJoODAKAu2jOVhoF3+6DAOBvcObWmE1H7QhmIA)

Answer (score 1):

That's because Typescript is based on [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

Suppose you have this :

```
type Column = {
  colId?: string,
  width?: number,
  sort?: number
}

export type ColumnSetting = Pick<Column, 'colId' | 'width' | 'sort'>;

declare function foo(col: Column): void;

declare const settings: ColumnSetting

foo(settings); //ok
```

`ColumnSetting` and `Column` are strictly the same types :

```
{
    colId?: string | undefined;
    width?: number | undefined;
    sort?: number | undefined;
}
```

Comment: Since Column has more properties allowed shouldn't it be possible to restrict the number of properties allowed in the definition of ColumnSetting?